# Where would I find the payload with a Wix webhook?

Tags: node.js, webhooks, velo

I have a couple Wix webhooks pointed to a couple routes on my server. The webhook is in fact hitting my routes, but I'm not seeing the payload anywhere. The documentation says it's in the form of a JWT sent in the body of the request. The body is empty though. Am I missing something?

Here is my route receiving the request:

```
router.post("/app-installed", (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.body: ", req.body);
  console.log("headers", req.headers);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: Hello my friend, did you find any solution? I'm facing the same problem - Thank you

Comment: facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You will have to retrieve the token from the body and then go ahead to decode it with your app public key. With ruby, I was able to derive the webhook data as demonstrated below;

```
  def wix_event
    require 'json'
    require 'jwt'
    require 'openssl'
    
    token = request.body.read
    public_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read('./key.pem'))
    decoded_token = JWT.decode(token, public_key, true, { algorithm: 'RS256' })
    puts decoded_token.first
  end
```

The decoded token has the webhook payload data.